# Using Rails Controllers to make a web request and then display data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, networking, stimulusjs

I have a rails controller that is making a web request, I would like to display the response body and status code inside of a view without saving the data to a model. I've tried using partials and instance variables but I've gotten no luck.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def create
    uri = URI.parse "https://#{login_params[:ip]}"
    http = Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port

    http.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https' # Use SSL, Should probably be default
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, headers)
    req.basic_auth login_params[:username].to_s, login_params[:password].to_s # Base64 encode username:password


    res = http.request(req, req_body) # make request

    body = Hash.from_xml(res.body)
    if res.code == 200
      redirect_to :show
    end 
end
```

Am I just better of making the request with Stimulus JS and appending the data to the screen?

Comment: Don't do HTTP requests inline in your controller. It has enough responsiblities anyways and controllers are notoriusly hard to test. Create a separate client object (a plain old ruby object) that touches the application boundry that you can test in isolation by just passing input into it. Also this is potentially an attack vector for a hacker - since you're taking an IP an attacker can make a request to any server under their control and can then exploit vulnerabilities in the XML parser. Why do you need to get the IP from the frontend?

Comment: It's just a specification my client asked for.

Comment: Should I use a module or a class, still not understanding the cost/benefits between the two.

Comment: a class. Classes you let create instances and encapsulate data.

Answer (score 1):

your issue here is you don't assign the value of your request to an instance variable for example you could do that:

```
def create
    uri = URI.parse "https://#{login_params[:ip]}"
    http = Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port

    http.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https' # Use SSL, Should probably be default
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, headers)
    req.basic_auth login_params[:username].to_s, login_params[:password].to_s # Base64 encode username:password


    res = http.request(req, req_body) # make request

    @body = Hash.from_xml(res.body)
    @code = res.code

    if res.code == 200
      redirect_to :show
    end 
end
```

then access it from the view like that:

```
<%= @body %>
<%= @code %>
```

Comment: do I need to add the  instance variables to my show action as well?

Comment: As you don't store the result of your query, you will need to redo the API call.

I would suggest to extract the query to a private method then call it from your controller. You may use some cache on it to avoid double query.

Post your controller and I will add my suggestions

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the response into an instance variable
2. render to the next action
3. Add this to the view:

```
<% if @resp %> 
  <%= @resp.body %> 
<% end %>
```